# How to resolve Duplicated gradle dependencies(jsr305)?

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

Everything was OK until I added **ObjectBox** to my Android project, So I get below error as building the project.

```
Duplicate class javax.annotation.CheckForNull found in modules jetified-jsr305-3.0.2.jar (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2) and jetified-jsr305-3.0.2.jar (jsr305-3.0.2.jar)
```

I even excluded `jsr305` from `ObjectBox` but it did not work

```
objectboxVersion = '2.5.1'
...
    implementation ("io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    }
    kapt ("io.objectbox:objectbox-processor:$objectboxVersion"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    }
    implementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:$objectboxVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    }
```

In the dependencies tree of `ObjectBox` that placed below, the `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2` is still there.

How can I exclude it?

```
+--- io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:2.5.1
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- io.objectbox:objectbox-java:2.5.1
|         +--- io.objectbox:objectbox-java-api:2.5.1
|         +--- org.greenrobot:essentials:3.0.0-RC1
|         +--- com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.11.1
|         \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of hours I discovered, `jsr305-3.0.2.jar` file is added in lib folder, So I delete jar file and the problem solved.